Detect auto-responses / OOTO notifications with AWS SES
I'm trying to handle auto-responses with AWS SES.
The general docs explain:

Auto response – The email is accepted by the ISP, and the ISP delivers it to the recipient. The ISP then sends an automatic response such as an out-of-the-office (OOTO) message to SES. SES forwards the auto response notification to the sender.

And

Make sure that your SES-enabled program does not retry sending messages that generate an auto response.

The notification schema docs explain:

Transient - General
The recipient's email provider sent a general bounce message. You might be able to send a message to the same recipient in the future if the issue that caused the message to bounce is resolved.
Note: If you send an email to a recipient who has an active automatic response rule (such as an "out of the office" message), you MIGHT receive this type of notification.

Our system is automated. I obviously don't want to automatically resend an email to a recipient with an OOTO, as that would generate another soft bounce (Transient-General), which would cause an automatic resend, and so on, ad infinitum.
The explanation above states "might", so it's not foolproof - the docs are contradictory. They state that "Transient - General" could be due to OOTO, but also could be something else. If it's an OOTO I want to ignore it, but if it's something else I want to automatically resend. I can't tell the difference between the two cases.
How do I reliably detect OOTO? I'm looking for official docs.
